# Comment getting posted twice

Tags: bug, comments, performance

Right now, I am working on a speed-"unreliable" network connection.

Sometimes, when I comment on a post, and network is unusually slow, after some time that same comment gets posted twice. This has only happened on this "slow" network, and not otherwise.

For example this comment: [Prove $\sin{x}\neq 2x$ for any $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561409/prove-sinx-neq-2x-for-any-x-in-0-frac-pi2/#comment9595941_4561419)

Comment: A typical case of idem*im*potency ...

Comment: Speed and/or latency?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum, the network speed as measured by entities like speedtest and fast.com was quite slow. That also implied a higher latency.

Comment: This hasn't happed to me, but I've seen a few other people post duplicate comments and I'd assume this is why.